# Windows.h not found using emscripten

Tags: c, windows, llvm, file-not-found

I'm trying to convert a C library in javascript using Emscripten on Windows. I used the tutorial [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Tutorial) to setup emscripten and LLVM/Clang to get started. I compiled LLVM with Visual Studio 2010. The version of clang is:

clang version 3.2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final)
Target: i686-pc-win32
Thread model: posix

On the command line, I write this line to compile my file:

C:\emscripten>**python emcc -v \mypath\myfile.c**

and this is the output and ultimately the error I get (and the reason why I'm asking help...)

```
emcc: compiling to bitcode
emcc: compiling source file:  \mypath\myfile.c
emcc running: C:\llvm\build\bin\release\clang -m32 -U__i386__ -U__x86_64__ -U__i
386 -U__x86_64 -Ui386 -Ux86_64 -U__SSE__ -U__SSE2__ -U__MMX__ -UX87_DOUBLE_ROUND
ING -UHAVE_GCC_ASM_FOR_X87 -DEMSCRIPTEN -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -U__CYGWIN__ -D__STDC_
_ -Xclang -triple=i386-pc-linux-gnu -D__IEEE_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-math-errno -fno-
ms-compatibility -nostdinc -Xclang -nobuiltininc -Xclang -nostdsysteminc -Xclang
 -isystemC:\emscripten\system\local\include -Xclang -isystemC:\emscripten\system
\include\libcxx -Xclang -isystemC:\emscripten\system\include -Xclang -isystemC:\
emscripten\system\include\emscripten -Xclang -isystemC:\emscripten\system\includ
e\bsd -Xclang -isystemC:\emscripten\system\include\libc -Xclang -isystemC:\emscr
ipten\system\lib\libcxxabi\include -Xclang -isystemC:\emscripten\system\include\
gfx -Xclang -isystemC:\emscripten\system\include\net -Xclang -isystemC:\emscript
en\system\include\SDL -U__APPLE__ -U__linux__ -D_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_DELETED_FUNCTIONS
 -v -emit-llvm -c \mypath\myfile.c -o C:\tempo\tmpn8yiq5\myfile_0.o
clang version 3.2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final)
Target: i686-pc-win32
Thread model: posix
 "C:/llvm/build/bin/release/clang.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-pc-win32 -emit-llvm-bc
-disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name myfile.c -mrelocation-mod
el static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pent
ium4 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -coverage-file "C:\\tempo\\tmpn8yiq5\\myfile_0
.o" -nostdsysteminc -nobuiltininc -resource-dir "C:/llvm/build/bin/release\\..
\\lib\\clang\\3.2" -U __i386__ -U __x86_64__ -U __i386 -U __x86_64 -U i386 -U x8
6_64 -U __SSE__ -U __SSE2__ -U __MMX__ -U X87_DOUBLE_ROUNDING -U HAVE_GCC_ASM_FO
R_X87 -D EMSCRIPTEN -U __STRICT_ANSI__ -U __CYGWIN__ -D __STDC__ -D __IEEE_LITTL
E_ENDIAN -U __APPLE__ -U __linux__ -D _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_DELETED_FUNCTIONS -fmodule-
cache-path "C:\\Users\\SS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\clang-module-cache" -ferror-lim
it 19 -fmessage-length 80 -mstackrealign -fms-extensions -fmsc-version=1300 -fde
layed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -
fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -triple=i386-pc-linux-gnu -nobuilti
ninc -nostdsysteminc "-isystemC:\\emscripten\\system\\local\\include" "-isystemC
:\\emscripten\\system\\include\\libcxx" "-isystemC:\\emscripten\\system\\include
" "-isystemC:\\emscripten\\system\\include\\emscripten" "-isystemC:\\emscripten\
\system\\include\\bsd" "-isystemC:\\emscripten\\system\\include\\libc" "-isystem
C:\\emscripten\\system\\lib\\libcxxabi\\include" "-isystemC:\\emscripten\\system
\\include\\gfx" "-isystemC:\\emscripten\\system\\include\\net" "-isystemC:\\emsc
ripten\\system\\include\\SDL" -o "C:\\tempo\\tmpn8yiq5\\myfile_0.o" -x c "\\mypa
th\\myfile.c"
clang -cc1 version 3.2 based upon LLVM 3.2svn default target i686-pc-win32
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\emscripten\system\local\include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\emscripten\system\include\libcxx
 C:\emscripten\system\include
 C:\emscripten\system\include\emscripten
 C:\emscripten\system\include\bsd
 C:\emscripten\system\include\libc
 C:\emscripten\system\lib\libcxxabi\include
 C:\emscripten\system\include\gfx
 C:\emscripten\system\include\net
 C:\emscripten\system\include\SDL
End of search list.
\mypath\myfile.c:4:10: fatal error: 'windows.h'
      file not found
#include <windows.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
emcc: compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

The C file does not use any MFC and as I understand it, version 3.2 of clang should be able to use the standard windows API. I checked if Windows.h is somewhere to be found and it is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include

Did I miss something, like a configuration or flag that specifies that I'm compiling with Win32? I also noticed that in the llvm repository, there is the Windows.h file located in lib/Support/Windows but I don't know what is its purpose. This looks like some sort of portability wrapper to use the standard C++ from different libraries.

I don't know where to go from there and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you have "-I C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1A/Include" on your compile line?

Comment: That's what I thought at first but since emcc is used to cross-compile, it uses the system headers bundled with Emscripten. In the Emscripten tutorial, it is specified that: "One thing to be aware of is if you build a project that has hardcoded includes, for example -I/usr/include/something: Using system headers that way is dangerous when you are cross-compiling, since the headers are meant for your local system, not for the platform you are actually building for."

Comment: I don't think emscripten comes with WinAPI implementation - it's not part of the [default distribution](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/include) and I'm not sure it'll happen any time soon: basically, you'd need to port WINE...

Comment: @SimonSenécal Any update on this?

Answer (score -1):

Emscripten does not have the required Javascript port of files such as `windows.h` or OSX's Cocoa.

The only solution is to port your code to SDL, as SDL is available in emscripten and hence its headers.